# Here tag ignoring trailing newlines

Tags: bash, sed

I am using sed to insert some lines above a pattern in a file. Example of the file

```
Stuff

Pattern

Stuff
```

Here is the code I am using to split up the file to insert text before `Pattern`

```
     patternline=$(grep -n "Pattern" "/my/file" | cut -f1 -d:)
     firstcut=$(($patternline -1))

     firstpart=$(sed -n 1,"$firstcut"p "/my/file")
     secondpart=$(sed -n ''"$abspathcomment"',$p' "/my/file")

     # Indentation intentional as snippet is nested within an IF statement
     text=$(cat <<EOF

Text I want to insert with one leading and two trailing new lines


EOF
)

     echo "$firstpart$text$secondpart" > "/my/file"
```

I am splitting the file using sed and inserting the text I wish in the middle and finally using cat to output the contents to the same file.

I expect to get (something similar to) the following output for the file

```
Stuff

Text I want to insert with one leading and two trailing new lines


Pattern

Stuff
```

But instead I get

```
Stuff

Text I want to insert with one leading and two trailing new linesPattern

Stuff
```

I'm not sure if sed or bash is stripping the newlines. How can I keep them when echoing the result to a file in bash?

Comment: In addition to the neat *sed* solution posted by Kusalananda, note that you don't need a *HERE* doc, even if you want to assign to `text`. Just use quotes: `text='  .....   '`. The text between the quotes can span several physical lines.

Answer (score 3):

It's the command substitution that eats up the trailing newlines:

```
a=$( printf 'hello\nworld\n\n\n\n\n\n' )
printf 'a is "%s"\n' "$a"
```

Output:

```
a is "hello
world"
```

---

Using `sed` to solve the original problem:

```
sed '/Pattern/i\
Text I want to insert with one leading and two trailing new lines\
\

' file
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
sed '/Pattern/i Text I want to insert with one leading and two trailing new lines\n\n' file
```

Here, we use the `i` ("insert") command in `sed` to insert a particular set of lines before any line matching `Pattern`.  By escaping the two newlines (in the first `sed` variation) we are able to insert them into the text.  The leading newline in the result is the same that was preceding `Pattern` from the start.

For the example data, this generates

```
Stuff

Text I want to insert with one leading and two trailing new lines


Pattern

Stuff
```

This has the benefit that none of the existing whitespace is modified.